# StackOverflowException in XNA Aiming Sample

Tags: c#, xna, stack-overflow

Basically, I am getting this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Sortie.exe."
I understand the reason for the error, that I'm getting a method to call another method that then calls the first method (or something similar to that) so an infinite loop is created.

Here is the specific line that triggers the error:

```
            float desiredAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(y, x);
```

The weirdest part is, all of this is, all of this copied straight from the [AppHub aiming sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/aiming). To the best of my knowledge, I haven't changed anything besides the variable names.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Sortie
{
/// <summary>
/// Sniper drones.  
/// </summary>
class Deadeye 
{
    //Vector2 m_DeadeyeSpeed; 
    Vector2 m_DeadeyePosition;
    Vector2 m_DeadeyeOrigin; 
    Texture2D m_DeadeyeTexture;
    double m_DeadeyeRotation; 

    #region Constants 
    const float Speed = 11.0f; 
    const float Lifespan = 600; 
    const float TurnSpeed = 0.04f; 
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Deadeye(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        m_DeadeyeTexture = texture; 
        m_DeadeyePosition = position;
        m_DeadeyeOrigin.X = texture.Width / 2;
        m_DeadeyeOrigin.Y = texture.Height / 2; 
    }
    #endregion 

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // use the TurnToFace function to update the spotlightAngle to face
        // towards the cat.
        m_DeadeyeRotation = TurnToFace(m_DeadeyePosition, Game1.m_Player.PlayerPosition /*Game1.playerPositionMirror*/, (float)m_DeadeyeRotation,
            TurnSpeed); 

        Update(gameTime); 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the angle that an object should face, given its position, its
    /// target's position, its current angle, and its maximum turning speed.
    /// </summary>
    private static float TurnToFace(Vector2 position, Vector2 faceThis,
        float currentAngle, float turnSpeed)
    {
        // consider this diagram:
        //         C 
        //        /|
        //      /  |
        //    /    | y
        //  / o    |
        // S--------
        //     x
        // 
        // where S is the position of the spot light, C is the position of the cat,
        // and "o" is the angle that the spot light should be facing in order to 
        // point at the cat. we need to know what o is. using trig, we know that
        //      tan(theta)       = opposite / adjacent
        //      tan(o)           = y / x
        // if we take the arctan of both sides of this equation...
        //      arctan( tan(o) ) = arctan( y / x )
        //      o                = arctan( y / x )
        // so, we can use x and y to find o, our "desiredAngle."
        // x and y are just the differences in position between the two objects.
        float x = faceThis.X - position.X;
        float y = faceThis.Y - position.Y;

        // we'll use the Atan2 function. Atan will calculates the arc tangent of 
        // y / x for us, and has the added benefit that it will use the signs of x
        // and y to determine what cartesian quadrant to put the result in.
        // http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx
        float desiredAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(y, x);

        // so now we know where we WANT to be facing, and where we ARE facing...
        // if we weren't constrained by turnSpeed, this would be easy: we'd just 
        // return desiredAngle.
        // instead, we have to calculate how much we WANT to turn, and then make
        // sure that's not more than turnSpeed.

        // first, figure out how much we want to turn, using WrapAngle to get our
        // result from -Pi to Pi ( -180 degrees to 180 degrees )
        float difference = WrapAngle(desiredAngle - currentAngle);

        // clamp that between -turnSpeed and turnSpeed.
        difference = MathHelper.Clamp(difference, -turnSpeed, turnSpeed);

        // so, the closest we can get to our target is currentAngle + difference.
        // return that, using WrapAngle again.
        return WrapAngle(currentAngle + difference);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the angle expressed in radians between -Pi and Pi.
    /// </summary>
    private static float WrapAngle(float radians)
    {
        while (radians < -MathHelper.Pi)
        {
            radians += MathHelper.TwoPi;
        }
        while (radians > MathHelper.Pi)
        {
            radians -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
        }
        return radians;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(m_DeadeyeTexture, m_DeadeyePosition, null, Color.White, (float)m_DeadeyeRotation, m_DeadeyeOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f); 
    }
}
}
```

1. List item

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be calling Update(gametime) inside of Update itself. this will almost definetly recurse infintely until the stack is full.

Comment: +1, yep, I think it should be `base.Update(gametime)`.  Good catch!

Comment: The easiest way to find errors like this is to make sure to check the call stack when debugging. In many cases you will be able to see the hundreds of calls into the method and know something funky is going on.

Comment: actually quick correction. cant be base.Update(), because  Deadeye has no base class.

Comment: Heh, my mistake =)  I was thinking this was in a main `Game` class (deriving from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`).  I didn't not read the code sample carefully enough!

Comment: Dunno how that got in there. Thank you so much! That solved it perfectly ^^